# adaFruit PN532 not seeing single Mifare Card

Tags: nfc, arduino-uno

I am using an Arduino UNO with a [low power blue tooth](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1697), and a [PN532 RFID/NFC Shield](http://www.adafruit.com/products/789).

I was having a problem where the loop in my sketch was not looping unless there was at least one card detected, and fixed that by modifying the library for the RFID shield `readPassiveTargetID()` function to be non blocking *(changed a while loop to an if statement so it didn't get stuck).*

Now the problem is that it doesn't seem able to read the tag id of any tags unless two are present.

**My Sketch**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "Adafruit_BLE_UART.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.h>

#define IRQ   (7)
#define IRQ2   (4)
#define RESET (3)  // Not connected by default on the NFC Shield

Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C nfc(IRQ, RESET);
//Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C nfc2(IRQ2, RESET);

// Connect CLK/MISO/MOSI to hardware SPI
// e.g. On UNO & compatible: CLK = 13, MISO = 12, MOSI = 11
#define ADAFRUITBLE_REQ 10
#define ADAFRUITBLE_RDY 3     // This should be an interrupt pin, on Uno thats #2 or #3
#define ADAFRUITBLE_RST 9

Adafruit_BLE_UART BTLEserial = Adafruit_BLE_UART(ADAFRUITBLE_REQ, ADAFRUITBLE_RDY, ADAFRUITBLE_RST);


uint8_t numChecks = 0;

String items[]= {"","","","","","","",""};

String lastList="";

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
 Configure the Arduino and start advertising with the radio
 */
/**************************************************************************/
void setup(void)
{ 

  Serial.begin(115200);


  //while(!Serial);
  startNFC();
  BTLEserial.begin();

  //startNFC(); 


  //while(!Serial); // Leonardo/Micro should wait for serial init



}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
 Constantly checks for new events on the nRF8001
 */
/**************************************************************************/
aci_evt_opcode_t laststatus = ACI_EVT_DISCONNECTED;

void loop()
{
  //Serial.println("--------------------Loop begin-------------------");

  // Tell the nRF8001 to do whatever it should be working on.
  BTLEserial.pollACI();

  // Ask what is our current status
  aci_evt_opcode_t status = BTLEserial.getState();
  // If the status changed....
  if (status != laststatus) {
    // print it out!
    if (status == ACI_EVT_DEVICE_STARTED) {
      Serial.println(F("* Advertising started"));
    }
    if (status == ACI_EVT_CONNECTED) {
      Serial.println(F("* Connected!"));
      BTLEserial.print("Goodmorning");
    }
    if (status == ACI_EVT_DISCONNECTED) {
      Serial.println(F("* Disconnected or advertising timed out"));
    }
    // OK set the last status change to this one
    laststatus = status;
  }

  if(status == ACI_EVT_CONNECTED){
    if(numChecks<7){
      numChecks++;
    }
    else{
      updatePhone();
      numChecks =0;
    }


    uint8_t success;
    uint8_t uid[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};  // Buffer to store the returned UID
    uint8_t uidLength;                        // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)

    Serial.println("CHECK #");Serial.print(numChecks,DEC);
    // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
    // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
    // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
    success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid, &uidLength);

    items[numChecks] ="";
    Serial.println("----------SCANNING------");
    if (success) {
      Serial.println("Found one!");
      // Display some basic information about the card
      // Serial.println("Found an ISO14443A card");
      // Serial.print("  UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
      // Serial.print("  UID Value: ");
      String uidChar ="";

      for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) {
        uidChar += "x";
        uidChar +=  uid[i];

       }
       Serial.println("ID:"+uidChar);
      //Serial.println(uidChar);
      if(!itemAlreadyExists(uidChar)){
        Serial.println("Its New");

        items[numChecks] = uidChar;
      }

    }
    else{
      Serial.println("No Card found");
    }


 }

}

// Serial.println("************************Loop END*********************");


boolean itemAlreadyExists(String id){
  boolean result = false;
  for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
    String s = items[i];
    if(id.equals(s)){
      result = true;
    }
  }

  return result;
}



void startNFC(){
  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    //while (1); // halt
  }
  else{
    Serial.print("FOUND PN53x board");
  }

  nfc.SAMConfig(); 
}

void updatePhone(){

  String itemsList ="";


  for(int i = 0; i<8;i++){
    String s = items[i];
    Serial.println("handling::"+s);

    if(!s.equals("")){
      Serial.println("NOT EMPTY");

      if(itemsList.length()>0){
        itemsList +=",";
      };

      itemsList += s;


    }
    else{
      Serial.println("STRING EMPTY");

    }
  }



  if(itemsList.length()>0){
    Serial.println(itemsList); 

  }
  else{
    Serial.println("EMPTY");
  }

  numChecks = 0;
     items[0]="";
      items[1]="";
      items[2]="";
      items[3]="";
      items[4]="";
      items[5]="";
      items[6]="";
      items[7]="";
    delay(5000);

}
```

**My Serial Output with NO Cards:**

```
FOUND PN53x board* Advertising started
* Connected!
    Writing out to BTLE: 0x47 0x6F 0x6F 0x64 0x6D 0x6F 0x72 0x6E 0x69 0x6E 0x67
CHECK #
1----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
2----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
3----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
4----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
5----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
6----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
7----------SCANNING------
No Card found
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
EMPTY
```

**With ONE Card**

```
CHECK #
0----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
1----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
2----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
3----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
4----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
5----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
6----------SCANNING------
No Card found
CHECK #
7----------SCANNING------
No Card found
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
EMPTY
```

**With Two Cards**

```
CHECK #
2----------SCANNING------
Found one!
ID:x19x153x28x212x0x0x0
Its New
CHECK #
3----------SCANNING------
Found one!
ID:x19x52x39x212x0x0x0
Its New
CHECK #
4----------SCANNING------
Found one!
ID:x19x153x28x212x0x0x0
CHECK #
5----------SCANNING------
Found one!
ID:x19x52x39x212x0x0x0
CHECK #
6----------SCANNING------
Found one!
ID:x19x153x28x212x0x0x0
CHECK #
7----------SCANNING------
Found one!
ID:x19x52x39x212x0x0x0
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::x19x153x28x212x0x0x0
NOT EMPTY
handling::x19x52x39x212x0x0x0
NOT EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
handling::
STRING EMPTY
x19x153x28x212x0x0x0,x19x52x39x212x0x0x0
```

That all said if i leave the two cards there they eventually go away??

Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Seeed-Studio PN532 drivers](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532) with my Adafruit NFC shields.

The Seeed-Studio version won't block and you can optionally set a timeout.

My [NDEF library](https://github.com/don/NDEF) has higher level abstraction of a Tag object which you might find useful for reading NFC tags. [Simple example](https://github.com/don/NDEF/blob/master/examples/ReadTag/ReadTag.ino). [Extended Example](https://github.com/don/NDEF/blob/master/examples/ReadTagExtended/ReadTagExtended.ino).

```
if (nfc.tagPresent()){
  NfcTag tag = nfc.read();
  Serial.println(tag.getTagType());
  Serial.print("UID: ");Serial.println(tag.getUidString());
}
```

Comment: I'll check this out.. thank you.. up vote for now.. Will accept upon solution.

Comment: Does this library work with rfid.. I just found out we will be using rfid instead

Comment: Don, I have two pn532 boards hooked up via SPI.  with your library how do i set the MOSI, SS, MISO, and SCK's  both of my boards will be sharing the same pins for MOSI, SS, and SCK but different pins for the MISO

Comment: I haven't used the hardware with RFID, just NFC. The Adafruit driver lets you set Adafruit_PN532 nfc(SCK, MISO, MOSI, SS). You might need to adjust the source if you use the Seeed Studio driver.

Comment: ok but where would i modify the SeedStudio source.. it only seems to let me the ss and not the mosi, miso, and sck.. im trying to set up multiple NFC boards on one uno